# Manga time travel

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

Anyone know the manga where this female time travels wakes up in a coffin with family around,she finds out she doesn't have this bracelet but later on sees it on this prince or someone related to that status..

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This could use more details; where and when did you read it?  Can you describe the appearance of the protagonist or any other characters?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: Are you certain the main character is female and not someone who was female but became male when they woke up in this coffin? Is this definitely time travel, as in going back in one's own past (or forward to their own future), and not a reincarnation or transmigration into an existing person who died, and thus was put in a coffin?